# vercel serverless function invocation timeout

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a next js app with vercel and I'm getting a 504 serverless function invocation error. The website told me to check the logs, so I did but I can't interpret what they mean. I attached a photo.
Anybody have any idea what's wrong? [image]

Comment: redeployed to heroku, checked heroku logs, was b/c I didn't have my ip whitelist for mongodb atlas set up write. Had to whitelist all ips

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Vercel/NextJS, and I'd love to keep using it, but I'm not sure how to whitelist my database IP on Vercel. Does Heroku automatically deploy NextJS /api routes?

Comment: @AngusRyer Thank you for reminding me to whitelist the IP, your comment fixed my issue!

Comment: To clarify my comment above--I'm using Google Cloud Platform for my Postgres DB and I had to whitelist my IP there. Since Vercel's IPs are dynamic, I had to use 0.0.0.0/0.

Answer (score 0):

check your getServerSideProps: Vercel has a timeout

when deployed to Vercel, it is probably exceeding the 10-sec max execution time (Hobby plan), resulting in a gateway timeout. In other words, you couldn’t load the site at all!

You can try the following

Bundle size (yep, size matters on the server side too)
Performance of the code in getServerSideProps()
Caching strategy
use client-side rendering